# While loop that checks if a number is even: Python 2.7

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a while loop that should check if the user inputs an even number.

```
pop_size = int(input('Enter an even population size:'))

if pop_size % 2 == 0:
     print int(input('Enter an organism length'))
while pop_size % 2 != 0:
    print int(input('Enter an EVEN population'))
    break 
length = int(input('Enter an organism length'))
```

I'm not sure where to put length, or the break.

```
Enter an even population size: 3
Enter an EVEN population 4
4
Enter an organism length 2
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```

This is what it returns.

But if I do this:

```
Enter an even population size: 3
Enter an EVEN population 3
3
Enter an organism length 2
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

The code still makes an organism even if it's not an even number.

The output I need to get is this:

```
Enter an even population size: 3
Enter an EVEN population 3
Enter an EVEN population 5
Enter an EVEN population 4
Enter an organism length 2
[[1, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]]
```

Explanations and links are appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly `break` out of your while loop. Updating `pop_size` in your while loop is enough. It could look like:

```
pop_size = int(input('Enter an even population size:'))
while pop_size % 2 != 0:
    pop_size = int(input('Enter an EVEN population'))
length = int(input('Enter an organism length'))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the order of the statements is out of order.  It would be easier if you kept the statements in the order you want them displayed.  For your example, it would look something like this:

```
pop_size = int(input('Enter an even population size:'))
while pop_size % 2 != 0:
    pop_size=int(input('Enter an EVEN population'))

length = int(input('Enter an organism length'))
```

First we take the input from the user.  While it isn't even we'll continue to get a number from them.  Once entered number is even, we'll leave the while loop and move on.  This keeps our logic a bit simpler and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong. The first if statement shouldn’t be outside of the while loop, and when you ask the user to enter an EVEN population, that value isn’t getting stored anywhere. This means that no matter what the user enters, the while-loop will break. I don’t know Python but this is what the code looks like in Java. It’s basically the same thing, just make the necessary changes.

```
    int in, length;
    boolean var = true;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an even population size: ");
    in = input.nextInt();

    while(var){
            if(in % 2 == 0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.out.print("Enter an EVEN number: ");
                in = input.nextInt();
            }
    }
    System.out.print("Enter organism length: ");
    length = input.nextInt();
```

The result from my Java code looked like this:

```
           Enter an even population size: 1
           Enter an EVEN number: 5
           Enter an EVEN number: 3
           Enter an EVEN number: 9
           Enter an EVEN number: 4
           Enter organism length: 5
```